# How to print data from a Map containing two array lists - One records from each list alternatively

Tags: java

Arraylist1 has Apple and banana(2 items)
Arraylist2 has Mango and Grapes(2 items)

Placing in a map

`Map<String, List<testdata>> x
x.put("a" ,Arraylist1 )
x.put("b" , Arraylist2)`

Now I want to print as below
Apple \n
Mango \n
banana \n
Grapes \n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<String> combinedList = new ArrayList<String>();
combined.addAll(Arraylist1);
combined.addAll(Arraylist2);

for(int j = 0; j < combinedList.size(); j++)
    System.out.print(combinedList.get(j) + " \\n ");
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy. It helps